# UI to allow 700+ multiple choices

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, user-interface

In my desktop .NET application I have written(*for internal use*) where I need to allow my users to apply diagnosis's to a Member Plan.  There are currently 700 in the system and growing.  I need to allow them to add multiple diapnosis's at once.  I currently am allowing this through a `combo check list box`.  This works but is **INSANELY** unweildly for both myself and the users.

What I am looking for is a how I could go about displaying these to the users.  Ideally I would need to show two criteria for each each as well.  `Diagnosis Name` and `Diagnosis Code`

Ideas?  How would you tackle this?

I am using .Net 3.5sp1 and SQL 2005 for the backend.  I don't care if the solution is **WPF** or **Winforms**.

Comment: Does the person who is inputting the data know the name/code already? If so you can use a smart filter to reduce the number of check boxes displayed when the user starts to type into the filter... see the following for an example


http://datatables.net/

with  a check box in each row. Might be a bit too much quick data for DOM manipulation though, you would need to test it on you target browsers/ machines

Comment: also you might be better asking this question on 

http://uxexchange.com/

as this is not a programming question

Comment: Goddamit, there's a uxexchange now?  But it will take me so long to get up to 6K on there...

Comment: @George Mauer:  My sentiments exactly!

Answer (score 6):

I'd use 2 listviews, 2 buttons and textbox.

One listview to hold the possible values, one listview to hold the selected values. The textbox can be used to filter the possible values (if the user enter MyValue only show the values that contains MyValue etc) and then the buttons would be standard button arrows to move the selected rows between the listviews.

And expanding on espais answer about drilling down, if that's possible maybe it would be better to have one or both of the listviews be treeviews instead, that way you could combine drilling down with filtering and be able to tell which ones are where etc.

Answer (score 5):

You need to flip your thinking.  It's not about presenting them with data, its about recording the users' intent.

When a user sits down to diagnose a Member Plan they are not thinking in terms of "which of 700 options should I select, oh let's just click some for the heck of it".  The said truth is that people rarely sit down at a computer because business apps are fun - they're usually using them to get some specific bit of work done.  In your case this sounds like they're trying to do a specific kind of analysis.  Each type of analysis can have several uses, you should capture that too.

All these concepts should be explicit.  For example (making up your domain somewhat), if there is an option to show all users that have a meal plan and an option to filter by users whose kids also have a membership it is probably unlikely that those options are ever used in conjunction. Instead you could ask your user what they would like to do: Analyze costs, or Analyze spread of membership.  Something like that.  Your users probably only use your application to issue at most several dozen *types* of queries.

Once you know what kind of work they're doing and what they're doing it for, I'm willing to bet the option set is cut down dramatically.

I've linked this a dozen times but [this herding code podcast with Greg Young](http://herdingcode.com/?p=189) is a must listen for every developer.

Comment: +1. That's what I was thinking. The options aren't the issue, the interface probably needs rethinking.

Comment: So you (two) are saying that if I understood what my users were trying to do better then I wouldn't have 700+ options to show them as the process itself would have narrowed the field down....correct?
Don't take this wrong, I am just trying to be clear so that I can understand.

Comment: Not you personally RP, you might understand perfectly well what your users are doing (though in my experience programmers rarely do with 100% clarity).  However, it sounds like that knowledge is not encoded in your application and your UI.

Comment: @Refracted. Not necessarily. You know your users' better than SO users. :-) However, what are your users trying to accomplish? They're probably not there just to check options... they are there to do something. There may, for example, be an opportunity to add the choices in sections. There may be a way to narrow down the options depending on the context. E.G. Eggplant, Onion, Tomatoes are options, but in the context of spreadable flavors, only onion and tomato are shown. Without knowing more about your app, that's as specific as I can get but it seems like it's a question of interface design.

Comment: I agree, programmer's RARELY understand there users.  That being said, I don't think I understand what you mean either.  These are just Nurses and Social Workers who are simply recording these things down.  I am **open to the concept** but I am having trouble applying this to my environment.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I will have to give it some thought as this is a *Nearly* finished LOB App we use internally and your suggestion, while valid, seems to suggest some major reworking/rebuilding of my app which I am just not afforded at this time.  Never the less, I will be giving it some serious thought, thanks!

Comment: So thats the first thing you can start with.  Are you a nurse or a social worker?  Each would get their own screen.  Suppose its a nurse.  Why are they at the terminal?  Are they there to manage patients (new patient admission? fix a data-entry error?) or are they there in a support role (analyze the patient for adverse drug reactions? get a chart print out for a doctor?).  You can go on from there.  There can be multiple UIs from which the same piece of information is entered.

Comment: +1 for the podcast link! I like me a good recommended podcast on application design!

Comment: Thanks George, I will give it some thought.

Comment: Its not strictly necessary to redesign everything (though it would certainly help).  You could ask a couple questions about the users role and purpose and then depending on their selection apply a stylesheet to your mega-form to show/hide/move around certain options

Answer (score 3):

You could either have some sort of method for limiting the amount of users displayed at one time...ie categorize them somehow (then you could 'drill-down' into smaller and smaller groups).

You could also implement a search that auto-suggests names as you type them to aid in limiting the amount shown at once.

Comment: funny, was going to write the same 2 options, lol. The drilldown could be a treeview or a series of list views.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement something like:

```
Available              Assigned
+-----------------+    +-------------------+
|                 |    |                   |
|                 |    |                   |
|                 |    |                   |
|                 |    |                   |
|                 |    |                   |
|                 |    |                   |
|                 |    |                   |
+-----------------+    +-------------------+

Filter: -----------
```

Where each box is a list view, the filter text box allows the user to filter the available diagnosis', and items are drag/droppable between boxes.

Once an item has been assigned, mousing over would show an inline delete button to allow the user to remove previously assigned values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there simply isn't a control that isn't unwieldy with 700+ items in it. Trees, listviews, comboboxes, datagridviews... they are all a pain (for different reasons) when you've got that many items.

I'd suggest providing either A) some categorization of the data to limit the choices and have a combobox to switch between those categories, or B) text entry that has auto-completion to reduce down the size of the items from which to pick.

For B, I'd use the (fairly standard) two list view, text entry and two button mode.  Hook up the text change event to "filter" the left list view, use the "Add" button to add the selected rows to the right list view.  Use the "Remove" button to take them out of the right text view.

You could get clever and reduce down the items by their name or by their identifying code - some people remember that a 012345 means something since it is commonly picked, for instance - or you could devise a different scheme for reduction.

I use B) in several products and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to George's suggestion, I'd just like to add that if your options need to be discoverable, grouping the options into categories can quickly get people to where they need to look.

However, be careful with this, because how a developer would categorize options vs. a user are often different.

Another option is creating a work flow and rethinking the interface. I know you mentioned they need to enter them simultaneously, but if there's an opportunity to create a multiple-page entry (similar to a wizard), it's far less overwhelming. "Choose options from category 1..." on page 1... and then next.  Careful again here to let your users know where they are in the scope of your application. Step 2 of 8.

There are many factors, including, how often the application is used, what skill level do your users have, what are you trying to accomplish in the end?

HTH

Comment: That does.  There seems to be 2 distinctly differnt answers here.  One short term, as in use 2 listviews, 2 buttons, and a text box and then long term, as in rethink your process, add categories, etc.

Comment: "The answer to a question lies in first determining what the right question is." ( If no one famous ever said that quote... I'm claiming it :) ) It may be that the textbox solution is the right one, but knowing how your users' will use the application is definitely key in determining that.

Answer (score 1):

From a historical use of data mining against a claims adjudication system and having to deal with diagnosis / procedure codes, you might want to switch to a combination of controls.  First, I would have a grid (allows more than 1 or 2 diagnosis, so your not stuck there and having to redesign a form if more are ever needed) of Entered Diagnosis Codes.   Above it (or below), have a textbox.

If the users have some documentation they are entering from and have the codes right there, allow them to free-entry into the textbox. During the validation of the textbox, query your table of valid codes and get the code and description to populate in your grid above if only 1 entry found.  If more than 1, display a popup window with a grid of the choices that matched your query and allow them to pick from THAT.  Any such chosen would be added to your primary grid display.  If NO Entries are found, that could be from a type-o, or a code that just doesn't exist.  I would then strip back the string until you queried and DID receive some result.  Then, like previously stated, call the secondary form to pick from available diagnosis codes.  Ex: if Diag code "12345" can't be found, look for "1234", "123", "12", "1" until SOMETHING comes back with a result.

Additionally, for the querying, if the text is determined to be numeric, query based on the code.  If alpha, query on the description... Either way, a result set could be displayed of what IS found instead of stumbling through a list of non-applicable items.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple text-entry field, with an auto-complete dropdown.  when a selection is made, add another field to the page for the next entry.